# MongoDB Error While Deleting Duplicates

Tags: mongodb

My duplicates deleting code (in MongoDB shell) is like this:

```
db.<collection_name>.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { <duplicated_keys>: "$<duplicated_keys>" },
            dups: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: { $gt: 1 }
        }
    }
], { allowDiskUse: true })
.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.dups.shift();
    db.<collection_name>.remove({ _id: { $in: doc.dups } });
});
```

And I've got an error like this:

```
[thread1] Error: getMore command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Cursor not found, cursor id: 144931661890",
        "code" : 43
}
```

What is the cause of this error? And how could I solve this?

**UPDATE**

- MongoDB version is 3.2
- Before `forEach`, the result is:

  ```
  { "_id" : { <duplicated_keys>: <dupkey_values> }, "dups" : [ ObjectId("56f8e4d37a88ea2aa938414d"), ObjectId("56f63ab87a88ea141ca33856") ], "count" : 2 }
  ```

  And if I find with `ObjectId("56f63ab87a88ea141ca33856")`, it is the duplicated document.
- The data amount is relatively large (30+ GB), could this be the problem?
- While running the query, there are insertions to the same collection.

Comment: @zangw Hi, thx for reply. No, not `_id`, they are some other fields making documents duplicates.

Comment: @zangw I've updated my question.

Comment: @zangw Strange... Could this because of the large amount of the data (30+GB)? Is there any limitation to the size of the cursors?

Comment: The same issue here? https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13358

Comment: refer the issue I attached, it seem the huge data is the root cause...

Comment: @zangw It is very close to my problem. I'll try `$out` first, thank you very much for the link.

Answer (score 5):

At last figured out the solution. The cursor in MongoDB has a life time, by default it is 10 minute. Once this time exceeds, shell can not find the next cursor any more.

To avoid this, set the cursor's life time with `noCursorTimeout()`. For example:

```
db.<collection_name>.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { <duplicated_keys>: "$<duplicated_keys>" },
            dups: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: { $gt: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "tempCollection"
    }
], { allowDiskUse: true });

db.tempCollection.find().noCursorTimeout().forEach(...);
```

Or use less batch size. For example:

```
db.<collection_name>.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { <duplicated_keys>: "$<duplicated_keys>" },
            dups: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: { $gt: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "tempCollection"
    }
],
{
    allowDiskUse: true,
    cursor: { batchSize: 0 }
});

db.tempCollection.find().forEach(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13358, this error `Error: getMore command failed:` caused by cursor failed in the aggregation. Refer to the same issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6036, it is planned to fix but not scheduled

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for sharing your finding. I was getting the same error, and adding noCursorTimeout() helped process my data.

Comment: Just to give you the heads up, there's an "add a comment" button under each answer which is better for little comments like this ;)

Comment: @BJ_ don't write an answer to say thanks... nor a comment to say thanks, just vote for the answer